# How to convert 0-3.3V DC into -/+10V? I am using a MAX3232

Tags: voltage, conversion, max3232

The 3.3V DC is output from a MCU.  How I can convert to a +/-10V signal?（0 for -10V, 3.3V for 10V.) If you can, please give me a circuit diagram using the max3232.

[image]

I just used Multisim to simulate this circuit as shown in the following figure, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @jsotola i'm sorry , this is my first time to ask a question on this website ,i have no idea about the rule. The edit has updated.

Comment: The MAX3232 does not guarantee 10 V outputs. What tolerances can you afford? What drive strength do you need? Do you have a ±10 V power supply?

Comment: Are you sure your simulator can properly simulate the chip? Why do you need to level shift the signal, what is the use for it?

Comment: @CL.yeah, i just found the max3232 does not guarantee an output of 10v from datasheet. so i have another idea that if i can supply ±10 V power, it seems to work  with a comparator, is it? it does not require much output current

Comment: MAX3485 drives the differential lines with 0V/3.3V. It's RS485, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAX3232 uses a switched capacitor charge pump. If you run DC simulation, it won't be simulated, because DC simulation is... DC. So it won't output anything. You have to run transient simulation and give it enough time for the charge pump to build voltage on C8 and C9.

However MAX3232 only outputs +/-5V, so you won't get the +/-10V you want.

You could make a +/-10V power supply (or maybe you have one already, if you have +/-15V opamps on your board) and use a standard comparator with a threshold of 1.65V (mid-level between 0V and 3V3) to do what you want.

Comment: Well, thank you a lot, another question, how could i  get a ±10V power supply from 3.3v DC? Could you recommend a circuit? Thanks again.

Comment: Where does the 3V3 come from?

Comment: Since I'm doing collaborative projects, this 3v3 is provided by collaborators.I think I want the system i'm responsible for to support itself.

Comment: Then either use a boost converter with an extra winding on the coil to make the negative voltage, or a more complicated charge pump. But if there is +/-12V already in the box, that would be a total waste of time and components...

Answer (score 1):

MAX3232 and other similar chips are "transceivers". They're not supposed to convert 3.3 VDC to ±10 VDC.

The 100n capacitors across C1± and C2± are part of on-chip switched capacitor inverters. As the name suggests, those on-chip regulators require "switching". So if you apply a continuous 3.3VDC you can't get level shifted signals.

Plus, the transceiver chip does not guarantee ±10V. RS-232 levels range from -25V to +25V.

Apply a pulse train to one of the TIN pins and see if it's converted into RS-232 levels. NI Multisim is capable of simulating RS-232 transceivers.